# How to fill array in sequence?

Tags: php

I have the following iterration:

```
foreach ($filelines as $indexrow => $line) {
    $columns = explode($splitter, $line);
    $row = [];
    foreach ($columns as $columnindex => $column) {

        $column = $this->prepareValue($column);

        if (RegexValidation::isNum($column)) {
            $row[] = $this->setValue('num', $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
        } else {
            if (RegexValidation::isMMYY($column)) {
                $row[] = $this->setValue("mmyy", $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
            } else {
                if (RegexValidation::isZip($column)) {
                    $row[] = $this->setValue("zip", $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $dataset[$indexrow] = $row;
}
```

I need to fill `$row` in a specific sequence, first is "zip," then "mmyy," then "num," etc. If there is no field, fill it as empty.

How to do this in the existing loop? Now I have a solution sort result array, but It needs to loop again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a special key and sort by the key. And - there is an `elseif`.

```
foreach ($filelines as $indexrow => $line) {
    $columns = explode($splitter, $line);
    $row = [];

    foreach ($columns as $columnindex => $column) {

        $column = $this->prepareValue($column);
        $counter = 0;

        if (RegexValidation::isNum($column)) {
            $row['C_'.$counter++] = $this->setValue('num', $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
        } elseif (RegexValidation::isMMYY($column)) {
            $row['B_'.$counter++] = $this->setValue("mmyy", $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
        } elseif (RegexValidation::isZip($column)) {
            $row['A_'.$counter++] = $this->setValue("zip", $column, $indexrow, $columnindex);
        } else { // If there is no field, fill it as empty
            $row['Z_'.$counter++] = ''; 
        }
    }

    ksort($row);
    $dataset[$indexrow] = array_values($row);
}
```

Use A for the group you want to have first, then B for the group you want next, and so on. If you want to preserve the order within the group, you should have leading zeros on the counter, because A_10 ist sorted before A_9. Change that to A_09, or A_000009 depending on the size of your dataset.